# can't refernce a file in ASP.NET API

Tags: c#, .net, api, dll

I'm creating an ASP.NET API, and I'm referencing some .Net dlls from another project, these dlls need to read a bin file on runtime.
I've tried to include these files in the bin folder but didn't work.

I know that when the project is up, it copies the content of the project to a temp folder "C:\Users\Mokhtar\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files" but it didn't copy the file.

is there anyway to make these dll see the bin file?

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the file you have added to your project. Set it to copy to output directory.

[image]

Comment: I did that, but it's not loaded though. here's a snapshot https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3F471921F9F5ADCF!427&authkey=!AGWrHBpALrc7TcE